# android room library and executor thread async problem

Tags: android, android-room, executor

```
fun setRecentToTextView() {
        executor.execute(Runnable {
            var tmp = getRecentFromDB()
            if(tmp.size <1){
                frameLayout1.visibility = FrameLayout.VISIBLE
                frameLayout2.visibility = FrameLayout.INVISIBLE
            }
            else {
                frameLayout1.visibility = FrameLayout.INVISIBLE
                frameLayout2.visibility = FrameLayout.VISIBLE
                content_textView.setText(tmp[0].content)
                currentRecentIndex = tmp[0].index
            }

        })

    }
```

First, getRecentFromDB() function has database access function by room library. So it should be called in thread that is not main.
Second, setRecentToTextView() function is for changing visibility of each frameLayout and setting textview of fragment.
But this occurs error because of wrong access to view by executor thread.

Are there any ways to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lot of choices:

1. runOnUiThread method (showed below as an example)
2. using Handler binded to main looper. It's almost the same as runOnUIThread.
3. LiveData - you should wrap value of your getRecentFromDB() to LiveData and observe it at activity.
4. Kotlin coroutines - you should use modifier "suspend" in your getRecentFromDB and launch coroutine to be able get result from it.
5. RxJava, Flow - similar to LiveData.

As an example switching to UI thread with **runOnUiThread**:

```
fun setRecentToTextView() {
    executor.execute(Runnable {
        var tmp = getRecentFromDB()
        // THE START OF UI BLOCK  
          runOnUiThread(Runnable { // will send it to UI MessageQueue
            if(tmp.size <1){
                frameLayout1.visibility = FrameLayout.VISIBLE
                frameLayout2.visibility = FrameLayout.INVISIBLE
            }
            else {
                frameLayout1.visibility = FrameLayout.INVISIBLE
                frameLayout2.visibility = FrameLayout.VISIBLE
                content_textView.setText(tmp[0].content)
                currentRecentIndex = tmp[0].index
            }}
        )
      // THE END OF UI BLOCK
    })

}
```